# Edição e Preview de Perguntas e Respostas lado a lado

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, interface-usuário

Sabe-se que quando estamos criando/editando uma pergunta ou resposta, o bloco de edição fica em cima do bloco de preview. Porém, eu particularmente não acho esse arranjo tão bom, pois toda vez que se está escrevendo uma resposta/pergunta grande ( *e.g* com muitos blocos de código ) e há necessidade de ver o preview do que se está escrevendo, é necessário descer a página, ver o preview e depois voltar para o bloco de escrita, fazendo com que, muitas vezes, a pessoa se perca na posição do texto que se estava escrevendo. Não seria mais interessante fornecer uma edição **lado a lado** ? Ou seja, deixar o bloco de escrita ao lado do bloco de preview e fazendo com que, conforme o usuário for escrevendo algo e o conteúdo for descendo ( scroll down), o bloco de preview vai acompanhando, descendo junto.

Comment: Também acho que seria mais útil dessa forma! :)

Comment: Existe um add-on que desenvolvi que suporta isto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4075/3635 - Disponivel pra Opera e Firefox por enquanto (chrome em breve)